# Image is draggable but not resizable? JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

As I saw on another questions I tried wrapping the img on a div and make the div draggable and the img resizable, but it is not working?

```
$('#container').on('dblclick', 'img', function(){
  $(this).wrap('<div id="resizeSelector" style="dislplay:inline-block;">');
  $('#resizeSelector').draggable();
  $(this).resizable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add jQuery UI to your html.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/acturbo/2QPkE/1/

jquery:

```
$('#container img').on('dblclick', function(){
    $(this).wrap('<div id="resizeSelector" style="dislplay:inline-block;">');
  $('#resizeSelector').draggable();
  $(this).resizable();
});
```

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm.gif">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a link to the ui-lightness.js on your page. This file is included on the css folder when you make a custom download of the JQuery UI